# error messages on implicit conversion to value classes

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Define a method which accepts types: List[_ <: AnyVal]

```
def foo(x : List[_ <: AnyVal]) = x
```

Try to use an AnyRef:

```
foo(List(new Test))

error: type mismatch;
 found   : Test
 required: AnyVal
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](self: A)ArrowAssoc[A]
 and method Ensuring in object Predef of type [A](self: A)Ensuring[A]
 are possible conversion functions from Test to AnyVal
```

Question 1:  In the warning message, why does the compiler ignore the other two "generic to AnyVal" implicit conversions defined in Predef.scala?

```
final implicit class StringFormat[A] extends AnyVal
final implicit class any2stringadd[A] extends AnyVal
```

Removing the previous ambiguity and forcing compiler to use the ArrowAssoc implicit conversion:

```
foo(List(new Test -> 1))

error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyVal
```

Question 2: What is this error message implying? Its confusing. The method `def -> [B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = Tuple2(self, y)` in the ArrowAssoc class returns a Tuple2 which is of AnyRef type. So, a more useful error message could have been `found Tuple2 required AnyVal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question first. Try this:

```
class Temp

implicit class Arrow[T](a:T) extends Temp{
  def -->[B](b:B) = (a,b)
}
def foo(x : List[_ <: Temp]) = x

scala>     foo(List(1 --> 2))
res0: List[Temp] = List(Arrow@2e17a321)
```

This works as expected. It is not complaining because it was searching for `Temp` and not `Tuple2`. 
Now introduce ambiguity:

```
implicit class OtherTemp[T](a:T) extends Temp{}
foo(List(1 --> 2)) //compile error
```

It fails complaining collisions. So to answer your question on why it didn't show `AnyRef` is because:

Remember `ArrowAssoc` is being called to get `AnyVal` representation. With `->`, it has a Tuple2 and is trying to retrieve a `AnyVal`. And because it is unable to retrieve `AnyVal`, it marks it as error as failure on inability to convert to `AnyVal`. Its true identity is irrelevant.

For first question:
In my understanding, implicits go as first search basis. So once it finds two and there is ambiguity, it quits complaining. May be this is why it doesn't try with `StringFormat` etc. This can be confirmed on repl by re-ordering implicit order

```
implicit class OtherTemp2[T](a:T) extends Temp{
}
implicit class OtherTemp[T](a:T) extends Temp{
}

foo(List[Temp]("asdf"))
```

Compiler complains as `Arrow` and `OtherTemp2` as collisions. If you re-order and run repl again, it complains based on which implicit was found first.
But I cant find an official source which confirms this.

Comment: Thanks Jatin. So, the confusion was the inconsistency of the error messages. In one case `Note that implicit conversions are not applicable..` & the other `the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyVal`  Both error messages are because of the same problem of collision right?

Comment: Yes. It is the same error associated with the same problem. The second statement is just an added description to the first statement.

Comment: I have another question: When the compiler sees `foo(List(new Test -> 1))` it will try to evaluate `new Test -> 1` to see whether its of type AnyVal. So, it does the following steps: It finds an implicit class which has -> defined and the only implicit in scope that has -> defined is the ArrowAssoc class. So, there should be no ambiguity here??

Comment: @Samar I have corrected the answer. I intermixed the answer before

Comment: Thanks, I still feel the error message `the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyVal` is quiet badly worded and confusing.